# Need a Excel Formula or Macro to count rows in a Table in a closed Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am searching for a way to to count rows in a Table in a **closed** Workbook **WITHOUT** opening the source file, either a formula or macro. I have the following code snippet that does this for a range, but it does not work for a table.

```
    Dim FName1 As String

'   Path to Family Mapping.xlsx
    FName1 = "\\ent.acme.com\IMI\[Family Mapping.xlsx]"
    
    'get row count of closed workbook [Family Mapping.xlsx] Worksheet "BMS-DES-POBA"
    Const ShName1 As String = "BMS-DES-POBA"
    Const ColNo1 As Integer = 1
    Dim ShNew1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow5 As Long
    Dim LastRow6 As Long
    Debug.Print FName1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set ShNew1 = Worksheets.Add
    With ShNew1.Range("A1")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('" & FName1 & ShName1 & "'!C" & ColNo1 & ")"
        LastRow5 = .Value
    End With
    ShNew1.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Debug.Print Trim(LastRow5) + 1       'add one row to count to account for Header row
```

I've tried the following formulas, but nothing yet seems to work:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('" & FName1 & ShName2 & "'!C" & ColNo12 & ")"
.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROWS('" & FName1 & ShName2 & "'!Table_Query[#Data])"
```

The COUNTA formula returns 1,048,576 rows, which is the entire length of the spread sheet. The ROWS formula returns #REF when the source file with the table is closed.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Im just guessing lying in my bed too tired after work to do anything, but have you tried the formula ="countif('"your code,"*" &")" or =not(countblank(,.. etc. Forgive me exhausted. I'd exhaust all options & methods I know before looking at/researching special cases of refering to closed workbooks. .

Comment: You need the Whole Path of the file. . From where it is in your machine .see - https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/33866-refer-to-closed-workbooks-cell-by-vba/ . That's it. I'm out.

Comment: So the above snippet works just fine.  It was my error plugging in the wrong file path.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason it wasnt working for you is :

A. The Path name of the closed file . Try changing those workbook extentions to `.xlsm` , and refering to them in full. And

B. `ShNew1.Delete`

I'm trying it now on my computer and its working. Im well chuffed.

**Get Rid** of `ShNew1.Delete`. Your `CountA` works as it supposed to on a **closed** `.xlsm` file.  And Just put the **whole path.**

.. `"C:\Users\User\Documents\... "` etc . Or whatever it is for your document and its location.

I should have asked first if renaming your closed files to `xlsm` and then running as shown, would be acceptable workaround for now.

I know you can mass-rename including the extentions, while they are closed. So if your happy with renaming your files `.xlsm`, deleting `ShNew1.Delete` and placing the **whole path** in Fname1, then it will return the correct values for you even when closed.

```
Sub main()


Dim FName1 As String

'   Path to Family Mapping.xlsx
    FName1 = "C:\Users\User\Documents\[MyFileName.xlsm]"
    
    'get row count of closed workbook [Family Mapping.xlsx] Worksheet "BMS-DES-POBA"
    Const ShName1 As String = "Sheet1"
    Const ColNo1 As Integer = 1
    Dim ShNew1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow5 As Long
    Dim LastRow6 As Long
    Debug.Print FName1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set ShNew1 = Worksheets.Add
    With ShNew1.Range("A1")
        '.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTa('" & FName1 & ShName1 & "'!C" & ColNo1 & ")"
        '.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTif('" & FName1 & ShName1 & "'!C" & ColNo1 & "," & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & ")"
        '.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTif('" & FName1 & ShName1 & "'!C" & ColNo1 & "," & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & ")"
     ''With ShNew1.Range("A2")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('" & FName1 & ShName1 & "'!C" & ColNo1 & ")"
        LastRow5 = .Value
    End With
    
    
    'ShNew1.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Debug.Print Trim(LastRow5) + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help David.  It appears I may have had error in my file path.  I am going to test it out more tomorrow.